# Unable to initialize the runtime due to low memory conditions

Tags: .net

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C# Project.

**Here is what works:**

- It runs without errors in Debug Mode on WinXP and Win7.
- It compiles without errors in Release Mode on WinXP and Win7.
- The Setup Project builds and installs on WinXP and Win7 with no errors.
- The Installed Application will run on WinXP with no errors.

**Here is what does NOT work:**

- The project does not run in *Release* Mode under Win7. The error looks like this:

  `MessageBox.Show("Unable to initialize the runtime due to low memory conditions.",
                  "AcpSuite.exe - .NET Framework Initialization Error",
                  MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);`

I have a break point set on the first line of my code (static void Main(string[] args)), but it is never reached before I receive the above error.

- I can compile a Release version, create a Setup, and Install the Application. The Installed Application, however, does NOT run on Win7. The unhelpful message it gives is:

  `MessageBox.Show("CLR error: 80004005.\nThe program will now terminate.",
                  "Suite.exe - Fatal error",
                  MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);`

**Troubleshooting Information**

The Event Viewer shows errors with Event ID 1000:

> Faulting application name: Suite.exe, version: 2.2.0.0, time stamp: 0x4c59b76b
>
> Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
>
> Exception code: 0x00000000
>
> Fault offset: 0x00000000
>
> Faulting process id: 0x688
>
> Faulting application start time: 0x01cb3408cb1ab283
>
> Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\ACP Software Suite\Suite.exe
>
> Faulting module path: unknown
>
> Report Id: 0d127454-9ffc-11df-b6de-00248103a942

**My PC**:

Windows 7 64-bit w/ 8 GB RAM

**My Application**:

I have the following "Non Standard" References in my project:

> a custom built DLL
>
> Microsoft's IWshRuntimeLibrary
>
> LabelView
>
> Microsoft.Office.Core
>
> Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
>
> Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms
>
> ZedGraph

All of these appear to work fine when debugging with them under Win7, but something is messing up whenever I go into Release mode.

My old Windows XP machine has been returned, so I no longer have it to develop on. Also, this is the only Windows 7 machine that I have available to test on.

How can I track this down?

Comment: Do some more clarification on what doesn't work, you say it runs without errors in debug mode on win7, later that it doesn not run in win7 debug mode and last that it doesn't work when installed in release mode

Comment: Wow, that's novel.  Your machine must be messed up badly.

Comment: @nos: My apologies. DEBUGGING in RELEASE mode does not work.

Comment: @Hans: Maybe. But if so, this is the only issue it seems to have ever had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

This solution has multiple Projects.

To debug the Project I was working on, I had to select x86 as the type of output.

However, one of the controls for this project (built and created with another Project in the same solution) had its output type still set to "Any CPU" when I was in Release Mode (but not when I was in Debug Mode).

It turns out the bug was surfacing every time the IDE attempted to create one of the forms.

Very, very difficult to solve!